# Open database Realm located in folder assets in Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a question,

i need open database Realm located in my folder assets but i can't

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .name("BaseDatos.realm").build();



        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
        Log.e("realm ",realm.isEmpty()+"");

    }
}
```

Comment: You should copy it and create inside app folder rather than in assets folder.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674982/realm-with-pre-populated-data-into-assets

Comment: You cannot open any files inside the assets folder, they need to be copied first. The above link should give you some pointers on how to do that