# How do I create a Realm DB for a React Native app?

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, realm

Maybe I'm thinking of this the wrong way, but how do I create a pre-populated Realm DB? For example, let's say I want to create a dictionary with 1000 words and definitions in it. The user can change the definitions from within the app, but initially the DB will have default definitions.

Can I create a .realm file with the 1000 words and definitions and include it in my app?

FYI: I am using Realm with React Native and I am currently testing using `emulator -avd CordovaAVD` to launch my Android emulator.

Comment: You should have a read on this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674982/realm-with-pre-populated-data-into-assets

Comment: That answer doesn't seem to have anything to do with React Native. It looks like it might describe how to do it within a native Android application. I'll remove the android tag from my question in case it's causing any confusion.

Answer (score 4):

I think I've figured this out so I'll post my solution in case anyone else might find it useful.

I have a function that will populate a Realm DB. Once I run that function, however, I want to grab that static DB and use it instead of generating the DB every time the app starts up. That's what prompted my effort. However, these steps will also be useful if you just want to back up a DB.

I am primarily testing using an emulator, but I think these steps will work if you test on an actual device.

**To grab the Realm DB from the emulator:**

1. Find the path to your realm file within the phone by adding this somewhere in your code:

```
    let YourRealmDB = new Realm({schema: [YourSchema]});
    console.log('YourRealmDB path =', YourRealmDB.path);
```

2. The path will be something like

   ```
   /data/data/(package.name)/files/(filename).realm
   ```

   "filename" will probably be "default"
3. From the command line, run
   `adb exec-out run-as (package.name) cat files/(filename).realm > (filename).realm`
4. This will copy your Realm db to your current directory

**Now, to use that DB in your app:**

1. Create a realm object:
   `let YourRealmDB = new Realm({schema: [YourSchema]});`
2. Set the objects path to your DB:
   `YourRealmDB.defaultPath = 'path/to/your/db/(filename).realm';`

NOTE: If you use a 'local' DB like this and your app performs a write operation, it will not write
    to your local DB. It will write to the db at `YourRealmDB.path`. So if you want to copy or
    view the updated DB, you will need to run `adb exec-out run-as (package.name) cat files/(filename).realm > (filename).realm`
    again to get the most current version of your DB.

I hope that helps. It took me quite a while to piece that all together.

Comment: Thanks for this, but when i am opening the file using Realm browser it ask for encryption key? where i can get that?