# Convert JSON to realm DB

Tags: json, realm

I have a large JSON file (50 MB approx) that I would like to convert to a Realm DB and use in my android app. Can I do this on my computer and then include it as an asset in the app? How would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot open any files inside the assets folder, they need to be copied first. Please, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33687715/4837089

Comment: I just found [this](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#json) ... Is that the best way to go about this? Because this looks like I'll have to create a dummy app, make the db, transfer the db out and then put it in the new app.

Comment: No, you can create your realm DB file with any data, put in into assets folder and on first start of your app copy it.

Comment: How do I create the db the first time? Does it have to be from inside an app?

Comment: You can create DB by Realm Browser on your Mac (if you have Mac or virtual machine) https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12 or you can init data from JSON in your app (on another test or debug application), then get it from your app into PC by using ADB and put it into your assets folder

Comment: You can also put the JSON file in the assets folder then read the JSON in the app and then write it to Realm DB