# Adding initial data in Realm Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm using realm and all looks good until I try to add initial data in my database.

I followed the example in this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674982/realm-with-pre-populated-data-into-assets#answer-37326580), so in my class, that inherits from `Application`, I have the following:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        final Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap();
        map.put("Key1", "value1");
        map.put("Key2", "value2");
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().initialData(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                int i = 1;
                for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    Category c = realm.createObject(Category.class, i++);
                    c.setName((String) entry.getKey());
                    c.setDescription("Category #" + entry.getValue());
                    realm.commitTransaction();
                }
                realm.close();
            }
        }).deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().name("realm.db").build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    }
}
```

And I thought this configuration should work, however I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Realm is already in a write transaction in /path/...

Is there something that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `realm.beginTransaction()`, `realm.commitTransaction()` and `realm.close()` calls. The `public void execute(Realm realm)` is a method of `Realm.Transaction` class and it will handle starting and committing the transaction for you:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().initialData(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                int i = 1;
                for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    Category c = realm.createObject(Category.class, i++);
                    c.setName((String) entry.getKey());
                    c.setDescription("Category #" + entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
```